# Fuzzy audio when Skype makes sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, alsa

I am having trouble getting my sound to work properly in Skype.

Every time Skype makes noise, all of my audio goes crackly, including anything else that's coming from other programs, even when the Skype volume is muted. I am quite sure it's something dodgy with the sound card, which is a Soundblaster Live! Platinum, kinda old thing but was good in it's day.

This is a sample of receiving a message.
[broken sound](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31026831/BrokenSound/message.ogg)

I just tried to record music with Skype messing the audio, but it is now working fine. This happens sometimes, it's not permanently fixed.

Fixed sound now sound like this (same sound as other clip)
[fixed sound](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31026831/BrokenSound/fixedmessage.ogg)

Skype input/output are all set to 'PulseAudio server (local)' and can't be changed to ALSA. Using ALSA fixed the same problem using Teamspeak which pretty much concludes there's something going wrong with PulseAudio, I don't know much about how sound works so I can't say more than that.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad
Questions has been answered here, works fine now.