# Overdriven/distorted sounds with Pulseaudio

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, skype, vlc

I'm experiencing some odd problems in some applications that use pulseaudio, in particular VLC Media Player and Skype.

The sounds reproduced by these two application sound overdriven, distorted, as if the audio is being processed by a guitar effect.

What is very odd is that the sounds being played by the two applications affect sounds played at the same time as well.
If, for instance, I'm watching a youtube video while i'm logged in skype, and one of my contacts logs in, the sound of the video gets distorted too.

It was easy to fix the problem on VLC, just by setting ALSA as the device, although this leaves some clicks in the audio, each two or three seconds.
I know somebody will suggest to simply deactivate every sound notification in Skype, but I'd rather solve this problem once and for all, before experiencing it while using another application.

Comment: Check [Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad/201747#201747)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).