# crackling sound

Tags: sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad)

Clean installed ubuntu 12.10 x64, at first skype was working well, but lately I have crackling noise, the video conversation not understandable, thus echo sound test sound just like that. Of course horsing around with blog suggestions, nothing works. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and although there were some bug-reports in the past about driver issues, i was now able to solve the problem by installing PAVU-control (Pulse Audio Mixer Control) or Alsa-mixer, and playing around adjusting some settings.

It may be worth a try.

Comment: I have been expecting specific solution, regarding skype crackling noise. Is Ubuntu know this issue? Any update? Or kick ass to MS?