# How do I fix the weird Skype noises?

Tags: sound, skype

How to fix the weird Skype noises on Raring? It sounds completely distorted.

I tried a guide from askubuntu.com so it ruined my pc so I reinstalled Ubuntu but how do I fix the weird noises?

Here it is: [Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad)

Comment: You're going to have to be much more specific. What guide did you follow? What does this weird noise sound like? When does this weird noise start? When does it stop? Remember, please *edit* this information into your question. Thanks.

Comment: It sounded distorted and it was the guide on here   http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad    (firwst answer)

Answer (score 13):

> Edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and add tsched=0 to the line load-module module-udev-detect

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
                     load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
                     load-module module-detect tsched=0
```

Save and restart pulseaudio

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

[Source](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/sound-on-intel-811b/)

It should look like this

```
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0 tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect tsched=0
.endif
```

Comment: will it be safe for me to do cause the last time i did that it ruined the bloop when i pressed volume up

Comment: yes it is 100 % safe, don't worry ..

Comment: Worked for me after a restart on a Thinkpad W510 running Ubuntu 13.04. Sound was playing fine for VLC locally and same with YouTube on Chrome and Firefox. Just was having lots of issues doing a Google hangout/phone call, all is well after this solution!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu-Mint as well... Any explanation on what is going on? Thanx though!

Comment: @ntg not too much just http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/sound-on-intel-811b/

Comment: my blog changed to http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/sound-on-intel-811b/