# Crackling sound and noise when using line in

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm receiving sound using the motherboard's "line in" input and I get a lot of "static" and weird noises.

The funny thing is that, when I try to record using `arecord test` so I can listen to the playback and check if the noises are there, the noise disappears and sound becomes pure...just by executing `arecord test`.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It's def a software thing. I listened to the audio coming in and it's pure.

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio may be the culprit:

Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Search for:

```
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1
```

and change it to:

```
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=2
```

Source: [Crackling sound from microphone recently, in 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315282/crackling-sound-from-microphone-recently-in-13-04)

---

If you are using [TLP](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#audio):

### Audio

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
```

Timeout (in seconds) for the audio power saving mode (supports Intel HDA, AC97). A value of `0` disables power save.

**Hint:** this setting can cause slight clicks in sound output.

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
```

- Y – powers off the controller together with the sound chip
- N – controller active permanently

Comment: there's no `options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1` in my alsa conf

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I'll keep searching. Hopefully someone else comes up with a better answer first.