# Ubuntu 20.04 Sound in YouTube intermittently stuttering

Tags: 20.04, sound, youtube

No matter what advice I follow - fiddling with /etc/pulse/daemon.cnf or /etc/pulse/default.pa or /usr/lib/alsa/asound.state - it makes no difference: the sound from YouTube keeps hesitating and sometimes I get a burst of what sounds like a square wave.

Comment: Details please what has been the fiddling. If we do not know hat you have done, exactly it is hard to suggest anything that you have not already tried.

Comment: would you mind running the command `sudo apt install inxi` and subsequently running the command `inxi -A`. This should provide us with the necessary info. If not, it should at least get us closer. Also, which browser are you using. If the sound only messes up with youtube, then it isn't `pulseaudio` or `alsa`.

Comment: Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-3: ARC Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  Device-4: Texas Instruments PCM2704 16-bit stereo audio DAC type: USB 
  driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-37-generic

Comment: I think the sound from my CD external hard drive is fine. YouTube videos and Teams audio are the problem. They both identically splutter, and occasionally produce what sounds like a square wave.

Comment: Nope - make that audio from my CD external hard drive as well !!! What a pile of crock!

Comment: So, I finally appear to have cured the problem after following https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158648/audio-stuttering-crackling-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer eventually!

I network to the internet by ethernet hard wired to my broadband box - but I also had wifi on.

When I turned wifi off, behold the stuttering stopped.