# Skype making high pitched noises - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, skype

I have a problem with Skype in Ubuntu 13.10. When I try to make a call or when any application sound plays, my laptop starts making high pitched noises that won't stop until I quit Skype.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This might help http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: The answer is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad the first answer works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you got "Skype generating neverending scratchy white noise sound for notifications"

Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and change from the code from:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

to

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Comment: This worked for me. I hope it keeps working. I will update if it is not consistent.

Comment: This has (severe) side effects including echoing in moc, overspeed play in chrome. The other answer doesn't have these side-effects

Answer (score 2):

user1039704's answer did not work for me but this command did:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

source: [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Also seems to work for other problems - in my case apparently wrong sampling rate.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with high pitched sound in skype from middle of 2018.

`load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` 
or

`PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30`
or

`resample-method = speex-float-10`

won't help anymore

Explicitly set in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 44100
```

(`default-sample-rate` already set beforehand)

And voula! Skype usable again!