# How to fix my sound issues with skype?

Tags: sound, skype, microphone

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a Lenovo Laptop, together with skype 4.2.0.11. When I use `skype` I can have different behavior:

- Microphone and Speakers work (i.e. sound in and sound out)
- Only speakers work (i.e. only sound out)
- None works (i.e. neither sound in nor sound out).

When I listen to music on a browser, with `mplayer` or other devices, let it be music or a video, I ALWAYS hear the sound without any issues. I have the problem (as far as I can see it) only with skype.

How can I fix it? What information do you require to give helpful hints?

I see the `mixer` on the lower right, otherwise I do not know anything about sound in Ubuntu (neither ALSA, nor PulseAudio or anything).

Comment: Anyone can help? Please!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

[Get The Sound Working In Skype With Ubuntu 13.10 ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html)

With the addition that in the Systems Settings => Sound => Effects  I had to turn the volume on Alert down to about 20% to stop a loud "buzzing" (feedback?) effect - even when there was  no alert(!).

Now to figure out how to get the video working in Skype ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I still have a problem with microphne, but the sound problems are okay now. I had to do something with PulseAudio, that what caused the problem.

[Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad?answertab=votes#tab-top)