# Cracked Sound In Ubuntu But Smooth Sound In Windows!

Tags: sound

Some sound files in Ubuntu gives cracked sound, but the same files run on Windows without any problem! Why it is happening? Moreover, when I record screen captures and record sound using a microphone, I hear crusty sound in reply. But same speaker works smoothly in Windows.... How do I solve this?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Edit: Sound card info...

```
*-multimedia            
   description: Audio device
   product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:45 memory:92600000-92603fff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad)

Comment: What sound devices are you using?

Comment: @the_Seppi How to check sound card details in Ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo lshw -C sound` from a terminal, add the output as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: @the_Seppi please see the output pasted in original question...

Answer (score 0):

Open `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add `options snd-hda-intel model=MODEL` to it, changing MODEL to the model name such as **acer**.

[kernel.org - HD Audio Models](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt)

[HdaIntelSoundHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)

It would also be helpful to know what computer you are using.

Comment: Hi. I am using Hp 450. So sould I write `hp` on model field?

Comment: I would try `hp-laptop` `laptop` `hp` `laptop-imic` `laptop-hp` and see if any of those fixes your sound.