# Problem In Playing Audio And Video On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, vlc, rhythmbox

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my pc. When  i play songs , it does not sounds clearly. I have I ball 5.1 home theater.  However same songs , videos I can play on windows 7 which I have in  dual boot mode on same PC.
I installed necessary codec for rhythm box player. But no Effect. Same problem on VLC too. 
But it sound nice on my headphones.
Does problem is associated with my iball 5.1 ch speakers ? And if then why it does not have any problem in windows..... 
Please Help me.
:)
Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skype and VLC sounds sizzle/distorted/bad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157891/skype-and-vlc-sounds-sizzle-distorted-bad)

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling and installing. The codecs could be a problem. I've had this problem. Convert one song (if you have time) using handbrake which can be downloaded from the ubuntu software center. If your computer has multiple sound cards try with each sound card. (Go to setting>>>sound). It could also be that the sound card is proprietary hardware which means you need to download the software to run the soundcard.