# Broken sound with ALC269 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Dell Inspiron Mini 10)

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, intel-hd

I just bought a Dell Inspiron Mini 10 with a Realtek HD ALC269 sound card and whatever sound it produces, it's broken. If I can't fix it, will have to put it back into WinXP and my little son will get used to M$ products!!!

Please help!!!

Some extra info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5babb67a654bb45c8cd1721ec716ed38f9f840c1

**Update:** This is how "Again" from Lenny Kravitz sounds: https://clyp.it/cwrslpt2

Comment: What do you mean by broken? Even a little bit of details would be useful next to none. PS: Given the lack of support for Intel's GMA500, that Dell mini 10 was not the best choice.

Comment: I know now :/ Sound comes out distorted, like if it was jumping from one place to the other. Initially I thought that it was skipping because of the under powered atom CPU, but did an htop and it tops at 45% during playback.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but I'd try [these workarounds](|https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting).

Comment: @mikewhatever: Updated the post with an example of how it sounds right now. Tried your workarounds, executing 'sudo alsa force-reload' on each change to alsa-base.conf, but nothing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close any open audio programs.
2. Stop the daemon from respawning:

`sudo nano /etc/pulse/client.conf`

Uncomment the line that reads:

```
; autospawn = yes
```

to say:

```
autospawn = no
```

Then press CTRL+X to save these changes.

3. Stop the existing PulseAudio daemon from running:

`pulseaudio --kill`

4. Now try playing an audio file from a media player of your choice. This will play directly to the hardware, but will mean only one program can play sound at a time.

**To revert:** Comment the line again (with a ;), and type pulseaudio into the terminal to start the daemon again.

**Source:** https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/choppy-sound-dell-mini-10/2401/3

**UPDATE:** If you want to keep pulseaudio active, edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, find the following line:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

and append "tsched=0" to the end:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

restart pulse (or just reboot your system), and the crackling should be gone.

**Source**: https://askubuntu.com/a/201747/52568

Answer (score 0):

The HDA audio chips need sometimes a manual intervention to make them work correctly. Try the following and see if it corrects your issues:

```
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel model=dell
```

repeat both steps with `model=lifebook` and `model=laptop-amic` instead of `model=dell` if the first step was not successful.

If you are happy with one of the options, you should make it permanent.

With `sudo`, edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=XXX
```

with XXX being the option you identified above.

I have seen one report of getting problem-free audio after `apt purge pulseaudio`, but this seems a bit drastic for me. But you can try if nothing else works - the machine works fine with ALSA alone, and on a system like this, you won't benefit from pulseaudio's features anyway.

Comment: Tried 'sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel' but I am getting the following error:

    modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.

Tried with '-rf' but still the same.

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` show? If the module relies on other modules, these need to be removed first.

Comment: This is what it shows: http://pastebin.com/sZsnCaNG

Comment: Tried the second command with the different models but no luck yet :/

Comment: If you use the second command, you need to restart if you can't remove the module. It's more tedious, but works as well. You could cycle through the options by changing the .conf file and restarting after each change.

Comment: Full restart, alsa reload or user logout / login?

Comment: Well, alsa reload might be sufficient. But it could be that a alsa restart still keeps the sound modules in place, so please do a full restart to be safe.

Comment: No luck :/ Still broken.

Comment: Is there a way to see through which parts of the sound stack is the music "flowing"?

Comment: Beats me. This sounds like a ton of effort, tbh. When all the 3 options are exhausted, you really might want to purge pulseaudio, maybe just for a try. http://ubuntumini.blogspot.de/2009/09/fix-most-audio-problems-remove.html

Comment: Better link: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/choppy-sound-dell-mini-10/2401/2

Comment: For reference, here is the full list of models: http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-kernel.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt;hb=HEAD

Comment: That worked!!! Will post the solution now. Thank you!!! Told my daughter that you helped me without asking for anything in return and she said: "It's like magic" :)

Comment: My daughter also prefers Ubuntu; I couldn't let your son fall prey to M$'s evil claws... ;)