# On installation I get buzzing noise through Realtek speakers plugged into audio jack

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Dell Vostro laptop with Intel i7 NVIDIA dual booting Win 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.3. After about 5 seconds of no audio signal I get a buzz through speakers plugged into ether the HDMI port or audio jack. I tried

"sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" then adding

"options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N"

that just didn't work. Any suggestions to eliminate the buzz?

Comment: Have you tried PA's `tsched=0`? https://askubuntu.com/q/897906/1004020